# Castor Collection Field to empty

Tags: java, xml, marshalling, castor

My castor masrshaller have an XML output as below

root>
 field1 /field1>
 field2 /field2>
  ..........

fieldn>
  collection>
      field>
        field>
        ..........
        field>
  /collection>
/root>

my mapping for the collection part is 
  field name="collectionObj" type="string" collection="arraylist">
     bind-xml name="field" location="collection" node="element" />
  /field>

The issue is when the  I will always have the collectiObj is empty
whole collection>tag disappears from the XMl output. Instead I would like to display as collection/>. Is there a way other than writing some fieldhandler, say setting some property to handle this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't find any alternative other than a custom field handler.. It is working fine...